# Why does reading images in another thread with QtConcurrent seem to cause a memory leak?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, memory, memory-leaks

I'm trying to implement preloading images adjacent to the one requested in another thread, and storing them in QPixmapCache, but even if I don't store the images, there seems to be a memory leak.

Valgrind shows no memory leaks with this method, but the program's memory will rise over to over 500MB, even if I remove the code adding the images to the QPixmapCache. If it's added to the QPixmapCache, the memory usage goes to over a gigabyte.

I tested to make sure that the FutureWatcher was being deleted properly, and, indeed, with the deleteLater call removed, the memory leaks much quicker and the leak is detected by valgrind.

```
QFutureWatcher<QVImageAndFileInfo> *cacheFutureWatcher = new QFutureWatcher<QVImageAndFileInfo>();
connect(cacheFutureWatcher, &QFutureWatcher<QVImageAndFileInfo>::finished, [cacheFutureWatcher, this](){
    addToCache(cacheFutureWatcher->result());
    cacheFutureWatcher->deleteLater();
});
cacheFutureWatcher->setFuture(QtConcurrent::run(this, &QVImageCore::readFile, filePath));
```

And here's what is run in readFile:

```
QVImageCore::QVImageAndFileInfo QVImageCore::readFile(const QString fileName)
{
    QVImageAndFileInfo combinedInfo;

    QImageReader newImageReader;
    newImageReader.setDecideFormatFromContent(true);
    newImageReader.setAutoTransform(true);

    newImageReader.setFileName(fileName);
    const QImage readImage = newImageReader.read();

    combinedInfo.readFileInfo = QFileInfo(fileName);
    if (readImage.isNull())
    {
        emit readError(QString::number(newImageReader.error()) + ": " + newImageReader.errorString(), fileName);
        currentFileDetails = lastFileDetails;
        emit fileInfoUpdated();
        return combinedInfo;
    }

    combinedInfo.readImage = readImage;
    return combinedInfo;
}
```

I expect the memory usage to not increase so dramatically after reading the images in another thread, and decrease over time.

If more information is needed, I'm happy to provide. I've been stumped with this for weeks.

Comment: Unsure of `fileInfoUpdated()` significance but that signal is fired when nothing was read altogether with `readError()`. Also don't do `const QImage` with `const` there as long as that will prevent from shallow copy and you don't want to copy right away.

Comment: I'd test if the leak disappears if you return just `QImage` or `QFileInfo`.

Comment: No luck with either of those things, unfortunately.

Comment: The memory appears to eventually clean itself up, after like five minutes. It slowly removes big chunks of about 120MB all at once. To cause the memory to become bloated, I just hold the arrow key in a folder full of desktop wallpapers and it sends 9 requests per image switch. I guess it's not really a leak, but why does the memory go uncleaned for so long?

Comment: Okay, so the problem is basically entirely gone if I allocate the cacheFutureWatcher on the stack instead of as a pointer, and simply have the function wait for a result to come through before proceeding (blocking). I still need to find a way to allocate on the stack and wait for the cacheFutureWatcher to finish asynchronously (this doesn't work with the connect statement). It's also worth noting I tried waiting and then manually deleting, but the same problem occurs. It probably isn't a problem with deleteLater then. Any insight on what exactly is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a bug report and got some insight from Qt developers here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-73413

Answer (score 0):

Qt uses internal caches for many things to speed up some operations, especially with images. Also, Qt spawns threads internally when calling `QtConcurrent::run` and keeps them alive for a while. The fact that the memory does clean itself up after a while makes a strong case that this has something to do with internal caches.

My guess is that what you are seeing are image caches that are kept for longer than needed. To make shure we know exactly where the problem comes from, please try the following things:

1. Replace `QVImageCore::readFile` with an empty method that does nothing but returning a simple integer (and possibly use `QThread::sleep` to simluate work)
2. Directly call the original `QVImageCore::readFile` without using `QtConcurrent::run`
3. Leave out the future watcher and instead wait on the future returned by `QtConcurrent::run` (blocking)
4. Same as 3, but do not wait for the result

Depending on the results we might be able to figure out where exactly the error comes from. Your last comment however confuses me. There should be no difference in behaviour between a stack allocation and a heap allocation with a manual delete.

If nothing helps, you can always try to run your application with a memory analyzer to find out where that memory is allocated from and who deletes it.

Comment: 1. Memory usage doesn't even move from idle, likely because so much code has to be nuked to do this that it doesn't load images anymore at
 all.
2. Behaves exactly as expected
3. Behaves exactly as expected
4. Memory behaves as expected, sitting at the QPixmapCache limit + the overhead of the program like the 2 others, despite not adding them to the cache manually. However, I can't use the cached images to load them more quickly because I don't have the keys for them (I believe). I did pretty much the same thing in my fourth comment as I just did in #3, except I used a qfuturewatcher.

Comment: Then you have propably hit some bug in Qt... I think your only option now is to use a memory analyzer to get to the root of the problem.

Comment: With `QThreadPool::globalInstance()->setMaxThreadCount(1);`, memory usage is as expected as well. It seems to be linked to multiple threads running at once, I guess.

Comment: Okay, for some reason the behavior only seems to occur on Linux... Really weird.